# make many datatables in the same web form asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to make suppose 2 datatables.
I made the first datatables use asp:gridview like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewlistmatakuliah" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Kode Mata Kuliah" DataSourceID="listmatakuliah" OnRowDataBound="gridviewlistmatakuliah_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridviewlistmatakuliah_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="mydata1 table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Kode Mata Kuliah" HeaderText="Kode Mata Kuliah" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Kode Mata Kuliah"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nama Mata Kuliah" HeaderText="Nama Mata Kuliah" SortExpression="Nama Mata Kuliah"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SKS" HeaderText="SKS" SortExpression="SKS"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am use javascript like this.

```
<script src="scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
        $(".mydata1").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
    </script>
```

Forms were given a very nice table. I love it. Pictures can be seen form the following table.
[The results are given table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVVrS.png)

Then I made a second DataTable using asp: gridview in the same webform like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewdatacluster" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="nim" DataSourceID="listdatacluster" CssClass="mydata1 table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nim" HeaderText="NIM" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="nim"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk1" HeaderText="mk1" SortExpression="mk1"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk2" HeaderText="mk2" SortExpression="mk2"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk3" HeaderText="mk3" SortExpression="mk3"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk4" HeaderText="mk4" SortExpression="mk4"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk5" HeaderText="mk5" SortExpression="mk5"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk6" HeaderText="mk6" SortExpression="mk6"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk7" HeaderText="mk7" SortExpression="mk7"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk8" HeaderText="mk8" SortExpression="mk8"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk9" HeaderText="mk9" SortExpression="mk9"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk10" HeaderText="mk10" SortExpression="mk10"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk11" HeaderText="mk11" SortExpression="mk11"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk12" HeaderText="mk12" SortExpression="mk12"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk13" HeaderText="mk13" SortExpression="mk13"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk14" HeaderText="mk14" SortExpression="mk14"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk15" HeaderText="mk15" SortExpression="mk15"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk16" HeaderText="mk16" SortExpression="mk16"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk17" HeaderText="mk17" SortExpression="mk17"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk18" HeaderText="mk18" SortExpression="mk18"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk19" HeaderText="mk19" SortExpression="mk19"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk20" HeaderText="mk20" SortExpression="mk20"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk21" HeaderText="mk21" SortExpression="mk21"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk22" HeaderText="mk22" SortExpression="mk22"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk23" HeaderText="mk23" SortExpression="mk23"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk24" HeaderText="mk24" SortExpression="mk24"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mk25" HeaderText="mk25" SortExpression="mk25"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="status" SortExpression="status"></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But given the results table to be strange. The images can be seen as follows.
[Image results for the second DataTable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2TS0.png)

I have attempted to try to fix it but to no avail. Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: "strange"? It doesn't look strange to me. What's the actual problem? does the top left cell have what you want in it?

Comment: The problem is when I want to create a DataTable form as the first image, the result is different.
Why attribute the first DataTable may exist on a second DataTable as the second image.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want your second datatable to only have two columns like the first image? Please be specific

Comment: No. you can see I want to make two different DataTable. But when I want to create a second DataTable, the DataTable design results are not the same as the first DataTable that has a search button and others.

Comment: So the issue with the second table is it doesn't have a search or paging on it.

Comment: yeah, as you can see it in the picture

Comment: There are a _lot_ of differences between the pictures. Like different columns, data. As it is, without scrolling around it's not obvious that the search and paging is actually missing. This would be far simpler if you explained clearly at the start instead of just calling it 'strange'. Anyway I suggest you press F12 and check whether the bottom grid has a class called `mydata` in it. If it doesn't then the javascript is not going to attach `dataTable()` to it. F12 will let you compare the two table and see how they look after rendering

Comment: Also use F12 to see if there are any javascript errors

Comment: sorry. my bad javascript errors

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the specific steps you took to solve this in the answer so anyone else coming across this could use the solution.